# How to see which GPU is being used in a laptop?

Tags: gpu

How to see in Rog Strix g513 laptop which GPU is being used? The laptop has Radeon 6800m and integrated GPU. Sometimes the rendering seems to be slow and sometimes fast. In addition, how to choose which GPU is being used? I am using Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: does [this reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-gpu-monitoring-and-diagnostic-commands/) help?

Comment: I am not not sure if I know how to check which gpu is active from the output of these tools. Interestingly radeontop can't identity the GPU being used. However, it was good to get to know these tools.